# "Unable to connect to the remote server" exception when sending a push notification

Tags: .net, azure, push-notification, azure-notificationhub

I am using an Azure Notification Hub to send push notifications to users of my mobile app on Android and iOS.

When I login to the Azure Portal and send a test message to a device ID it works OK.

I create the `NotificationHubClient` using the connection string with policy name `DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature` that I get from the Azure Portal.

```
NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString("Endpoint=sb://redacted.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature;SharedAccessKey=redacted", "redacted");
```

I am currently trying to send a notification in the simplest way I can:

```
Notification notification = new GcmNotification(message);
PushNotifications.Instance.Hub.SendNotificationAsync(notification, fakeUser.Devices).Wait();
```

I get an `AggregateException` with an `Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs.Messaging.MessagingCommunicationException` inside it.

The relevant details that I can see from the inner exception:

`Message`: Unable to connect to the remote server
`Inner Exception Message`: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 23.101.228.99:443 *(appears to be a Microsoft IP address)*
`Detail.ErrorCode`: 60000
`Detail.ErrorLevel`: Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs.Messaging.MessagingExceptionDetail.ErrorLevelType.UserError

Comment: How did you solve your problem Coxy?.I am also facing the same issue.Please help me to resolve the issue

Comment: @PraveenBaruri I'm afraid we never solved this issue. If you're running into it was well, then I guess MS never fixed the NotificationHubClient to work through a HTTP Proxy.

Comment: We had this error message this morning on our Push Client.  We rebooted the software and it started working, Very stage. almost like a bug in the azure push notification clinet.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an issue with connecting to Azure through a HTTP proxy.
I can't reproduce it on another machine that is using a phone as a personal hotspot.

Comment: We get this issue on a VM hosted in a data centre with no HTTP Proxy setup?  How do we debug further?